# Does server SSL certificate update require SQL Service restart

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, ssl, certificate

This seems like such a basic question but I'm not finding it anywhere else on the site so apologies in advance if this is a repeat.

Some co-workers and I are trying to determine if a restart of the SQL Service is required on a SQL Server 2019 instance when the server's SSL certificate is updated. The instance is set to encrypt connections and the most I can find on Microsoft's documentation is that a SQL service restart is required when *initially configuring* SQL Server to encrypt connections. No documentation (that I can find) about whether a SQL Service restart is required for subsequent SSL updates.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

> [...] if a restart of the SQL Service is required on a SQL Server 2019 instance when the server's SSL certificate is updated.

Yes you'll need to restart. All this does is set a registry key which is only scanned on startup.